# Fix Trim size 6.125in x 9.25 in using memoir

Tags: memoir

I've tried with:

```
\documentclass[10pt,smallroyalvopaper,oldfontcommands]{memoir} 

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-9]

\end{document}
```

I got the `PDF` output with `Trim size` as `6.175 inches x 9.25 inches` because of the option `smallroyalvopaper` used, but I need the Trim should be as `6.125in x 9.25 inches` with the same `text width` and `height` of the option `smallroyalvopaper` also the page should be both side equal, i.e., `text width` should be `center` to the `Trim size` on both `odd` and `even` pages...

Please advise...

Comment: Please advise exactly what you mean by trim size 6.125x9.25 because that is what Peter already told you. I have a felling you want the outputted papersize to have that size, that is not what trimming is about. Trimming is when you print on one size of paper, but is designing a doc of smaller size to be physically cut to the trimmed size. I think you're looking for a method for examples explicitly setting the stock size to this specific size

Comment: I meant the Trim size as paper width and height

Comment: Then you used the wording. As mentioned trimmed size is something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Peter Wilson` answer working fine, with a small addition, and the modified `MWE` is:

```
    % memtrimprob.tex SE 642484

\documentclass[10pt,smallroyalvopaper,oldfontcommands]{memoir} 

\stockheight=9.25in
\stockwidth=6.125in
\settrimmedsize{\stockheight}{\stockwidth}{*} % set the trimmed size
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{*} % equal left/right margins
\checkandfixthelayout

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-9]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't think this adds anything to my answer. The `smallroyalvopaper` class option sets the stock dimensions (plus some other dimensions) so no need to specify them again. Further if the class option had been, say `a4paper' your suggested MWE would have reported problems.

Comment: Yes, this works for me and thanks

Comment: @PeterWilson the OP wanted the stock size to have a width of `6.125in`, `smallroyalvopaper` sets `\stockwidth=6.175in`. Your example does not change the stock size

Comment: @MadyYuvi the `memoir` say of setting the stock would be `\setstocksize{9.25in}{6.125in}` (that sets those two lengths)

Comment: @daleif The OP added a clarification of what was wanted after I gave my answer. To me the implication of MadyYuvi's answer is that it would apply to any `memoir` papersize option. Try it, for example,  with the `a4paper` option and there will be problems. (in any case I find it hard to believe that the OP will be printing on `smallroyalvopaper`; it's very difficult to buy that size of paper.)

Comment: @PeterWilson I just think the OP didn't have the proper vocabulary

Comment: @daleif Maybe, but others  should have.

Comment: @PeterWilson it took me a while to figure out what the OP was after

Comment: @PeterWilson and `daleif` So sorry, if my words are not clear, will take care in future

Comment: @GowriSaro I realise that English is not your first language and I think that you did very well. Some bits of LaTeX are not easy to understand·

Answer (score 4):

I think that this will do it for you.

```
% memtrimprob.tex SE 642484

\documentclass[10pt,smallroyalvopaper,oldfontcommands]{memoir} 

\settrimmedsize{9.25in}{6.125in}{*} % set the trimmed size
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{*} % equal left/right margins
\checkandfixthelayout

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-9]

\end{document}
```

Read the manual for more information, especially **Chapter Two** Laying out the page.

**EDIT FOLLOWING OP'S COMMENT**

Please read the manual, especially the 2nd chapter **Laying out the page**.

There is a distinction between the size of the stock paper which will be printed on (usually specified by the `memoir` class paper options --- `smallroyalvopaper` in your case) and the size of the paper when published --- the trimmed size.

In the physical world of printing and publishing, printing is done on specific sizes of paper which are then trimmed to the size for issue to the public. The trimmed size is obviously smaller than the stock size as it is obtained by physically cutting off portions of the printed stock paper.

My MWE provided the trimmed size you wanted. In my MWE you could change the `smallroyalvopaper` option to `a4paper` but still get the same trimmed size.

Comment: Sorry, but still the output page size showed as `6.175 x 9.25 inches`... Please advise...